# how to make Gridview textbox's border color red while validating using jquery or javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have gridview with textbox fields. In a button click need to validate textbox value.If textbox contains 0 or 0.00,then need to change  textbox's border  color red.

How to do with jQuery or javascript

Please help me..

Thanks in advance..

Deepthi..

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code of Jquery

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' name='testtext'>
```

**JQuery**

```
$("input[name='testtext'").change(function(){
     if($(this).val() == 0) {
         $(ele).css('border','1px #B87574 solid');
     }
}
```

`$(this).css()` is used to change css elements.